# how to insert a image to .rtf where cursor on file

Tags: wpf, image, rtf

I load a .rtf file  content to a RichTextBox in a WPF application ,now  i  want to insert a image to  .rtf file  content where cursor on file in RichTextBox .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FlowDocument content of the RicheTextBox to achieve this.

RichTextBox exposes its contents as a FlowDocument:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx

which you can then insert an image into:
http://wpfhacks.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-insert-image-into-flowdocument.html

You can get the cursor's position in the FlowDocument using the CaretPosition of the RichTextBox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition.aspx

The TextPointer object gives you all the information you need to determine the elements in the FlowDocument that you want to insert your image next to.

Comment: i am sorry,maybe i did not express clearly.i  want to insert   several images  to .rtf file content not to a control , and the location of the pictures is appointed in .rtf file .so when  the .rtf file is loaded to richtextbox control  ,the  content of .rtf will be exposed. now i do not know how to make mark at the place i want,i do not know how to insert images.thanks

Comment: Why not do the above then save back to the RTF file? If you don't want to get the RichTextBox control involved at all, you can use a RTF file API like DevExpress's DocumentServer.